# Where can I find authentic areas in Canary islands?

Tags: spain, tourist-traps, canary-islands, tenerife

I am going on a trip to the Canary Islands and I have heard that it is quite commercial in some areas.

Does anyone know of the authentic and more "virgin" regions, "off the beaten track," particularly in Tenerife?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Travel.SE. Please take a moment to read the [faq](http://travel.stackexchange.com/faq) as that clarifies what sort of questions should be asked here.
Right now your question is a bit broad. What are you looking for in these "nicer" regions? Do you want to hike? Buy local products? Or just want to see a local village? Could you be more specific in your question?

Comment: It's a very popular destination, for various good reasons. More or less one third of the GDP of the Canary Islands comes from tourism! If you want something less "commercial", go to one of the smaller islands: La Palma, El Hierro or La Gomera.

Comment: I have clarified the question somewhat, and second the nomination for reopening.

Answer (score 7):

1. With regards to Tenerife:

   http://therealtenerife.com/

   This website is devoted to the parts of Tenerife that most websites gloss over. Most people’s holidays to Tenerife tend to involve heading to the sunny, purpose built resorts of the south. However much of the rest of Tenerife is where the Canarios live, work and play; a place where traditions and culture thrive.

   Written by a couple from Manchester, UK who have lived in the North of Tenerife since 2003.

   You won't find Playa de Las Americas or Los Christianos on this website.

   They also have a number of other websites regarding Tenerife inc.

   http://realtenerife.wordpress.com/

   http://walkingtenerife.co.uk/
2. Corralejo is one of the best choice however I always recommend that people going for the first time hire a car from the airport and see the interior of the island as well as the south's resorts and beaches. Check http://www.corralejo.org for more information.
   El Cotillo's lagoons & good restaurant hunting all over the island :)

Answer (score 5):

I highly recommend visiting El Teide, the large volcano at the centre of Tenerife. It attracts visitors, but as it's quite remote, only the more adventurous bother to go there. The Teide National Park, which surrounds the volcano is a UNESCO World Heritage Site.
The cable car ride up the volcano is definitely worth a look, and the last 500 feet of walking to the summit is very worthwhile, as the views from the peak are fantastic. Several of the other Canary islands are visible. You need to apply for a permit to walk the path to the summit, which you can apply for at this email address: teide@oapn.mma.es
When I went in 2008, you had to apply in advance and provide the names and passport numbers of all who want to climb, plus your preferred dates and times, as numbers are limited.